# Left JOIN give incorrect total sum result

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table on (daily_book and extra_cost) so structure is

**daily_book**

```
db_id | refund                
1     |  7161                 
2     |  5980
```

**extra_cost**

```
ec_id  |  db_id    | cost
1      |   1       |  156
2      |   1       |  123
3      |   2       |  100
4      |   2       |  120
```

So I get total refund value and total cost value in one row.

So my query is

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(d.refund) AS refund, SUM(e.cost) AS e_cost FROM `daily_book` d LEFT JOIN extra_cost e ON (d.db_id = e.db_id) WHERE d.db_id > 0";
```

I got result is 26,282 for refund and 499 for total cost; that's incorrect.

I want result is 13,141 for refund and 499 for total cost.

Comment: You might also get some valuable help from http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should become more familiar with how SQL JOINs work before moving on to aggregate functions such as `sum()`.  If you removed the aggregate function calls from your query, you'll see the duplicated rows in the JOIN result which give you the unexpected refund total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mystery here.  You are aggregating *multiple rows* for the refund.  You need to do the aggregations separately.  In MySQL, this is a bit cumbersome, but here is one method:

```
SELECT dd.refund, SUM(e.cost) AS e_cost
FROM daily_book d LEFT JOIN
     extra_cost e
     ON (d.db_id = e.db_id) CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(d.refund) as refund FROM daily_book d WHERE d.db_id > 0) dd
WHERE d.db_id > 0;
```

Comment: Hey thanks sir...now solve sir...again thanks

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem then please accept the answer. [**How to accept answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) @KrunalJSathavaraKinjal